# Abbreviate in R

Tags: r

I have the following code

```
  attrWeights = list(time    = exp(b_tt)/(exp(b_tt)+exp(b_tc)+exp(b_hw)+exp(b_ch)),
                     cost    = exp(b_tc)/(exp(b_tt)+exp(b_tc)+exp(b_hw)+exp(b_ch)),
                     headway = exp(b_hw)/(exp(b_tt)+exp(b_tc)+exp(b_hw)+exp(b_ch)),
                     changes = exp(b_ch)/(exp(b_tt)+exp(b_tc)+exp(b_hw)+exp(b_ch)))
```

It's pretty cumbersome to type in the denominator many times. Is there a way to simplify, such that

`time = exp(b)/ c`, where `c` is the summation of all the exponent terms?

thanks.

Comment: Your equations are inconsistent: you first list `a` over the sums of exponentiated `b` and `c`, but when you define `y` (as the sum of ..), you then divide `a` by `b`, not by `y`. Am I missing something? (This is before AnilGoyal's edit that assumed you should have `y` in the denominator ... perhaps yours was just a typo?)

Comment: @r2evans, I am assuming he means `x = a/y`

Comment: I was thinking the same, but ... the question now has code that resolves the question, suggesting that I'm missing something else or the edit to the code resolves the question.

Comment: Just calculate it once with assignment to a meaningful  name like `denom`.

Comment: Thanks for the answers so far. The b_x terms to be estimated, thus the denominator are strings, to be fed in to another function, rather than numerical values at this point.

Comment: That last comment is very confusing to me. Please make this question a bit more reproducible, ensuring that we can try all of your code and apply it with some expected output. The gold-standard for sample data is with `dput(x)`, where `x` is a representative sample of data; it doesn't need to be all-rows, all-columns, just something *representative*. I suggest you read https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info, then come back and add some more material to your question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Its hard sometimes to ask a question the right way, especially when one is new to R.

To answer my own question, we can do something like this:

denom <- c("(exp(b_tt)+exp(b_tc)+exp(b_hw)+exp(b_ch)")

time <- paste0("exp(b_tt)/(", denom,")")

Adding it back to the list should be trivial.

Thanks you for your help!